# How to create and set values for attribute in XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom

How to create and set values for attribute in XML ? I need to set ateam id="101" ?
With this I listed my code. By using createAttribute i created but i dont know how to set value for that attribute..

```
/* create XML Content */
 $domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
 $xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("xml");
 $xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);
 $currentTrack = $domtree->createElement("messsage");
 $currentTrack = $xmlRoot->appendChild($currentTrack);
 $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('category','Scores'));
 $Game = $currentTrack->appendChild($domtree->createElement('Game',''));
 $Game->appendChild($v = $domtree->createElement('ateam','India'));
 $Game->appendChild($domtree->createElement('score',30));
 $v->appendChild($domtree->createAttribute('id'));
  echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <messsage>
        <category>Scores</category>
        <Game>
            <ateam id="">India</ateam>
            <score>30</score>
        </Game>
    </messsage>
</xml>
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml>
        <messsage>
            <category>Scores</category>
            <Game>
                <ateam id="101">India</ateam>
                <score>30</score>
            </Game>
        </messsage>
    </xml>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is using [`setAttribute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php):

```
$v->setAttribute('id', 101);
```

Comment: Thanks .. I try setAttribute with single parameter.. now got a solution